# JSF html namespace does not work

Tags: html, jsf, maven

I'm working with a maven project that deploys a WAR archive to a project that deploys an EAR archive to a JBoss server.

Here is my Facelets code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>title</title>
</h:head>
<h:form>

    <h:body>
        <input type="button" value="babap"></input>
        <h1>Ueberschrift</h1>

        <p>paragraph</p>

        <h:outputText value="outputText" />

        text at bottom
    </h:body>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Everything seems to work except for `<h:outputtext>`. it simply doesn't show up on the website. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *everything seems to work except for h:outputtext. it simply doesn't show up on the website.*

Did the request URL (the URL as you see in browser's address bar) match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`? If not, then it won't be invoked and thus all the JSF works just won't be performed.

You need to make sure that the request URL matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. If it's mapped on `*.jsf`, then open the page by `/foo.jsf` instead of `/foo.xhtml`. Or, better, just change the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` to `*.xhtml`. This way you never need to worry about virtual URLs.